# Fullcalendar Scheduler resource refetch not updating vertical resource view

Tags: fullcalendar, scheduler

I have a problem with updating resources using fullcalendar scheduler plugin.
I use a vertical resource view. Oddly enough this problem does not happen in timeline view.

I use a function to (re)fetch resources, let's say it's something simple, for purposes of an example, as:

```
var t = this;
t.someParam = false;
$(el).fullCalendar({
    resources: function(callback){
            //do stuff
            if(t.someParam === true){
                callback([{id: 1, title: 'title'}]);
            }
            else{
                callback([{id: 2, title: 'title2'}]);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This means when i do a refetch, i call

```
$(el).fullCalendar('refetchResources')
```

The fetch works (resources callback is called). Also, before the refetch, i set a parameter (e.g "someParam") to some value ( true), which affects the results (see example), just to simulate differing results. The results are a working array and if i call

```
$(el).fullCalendar('getResources') //after refetch
```

the intended resources have been added to the calendar.
The problem is, the resources will not render in the view, until i skip to another view or change the date. I tried 'render' function, but this doesn't work. I would not want to use 'addResource' (preferably), even though this would render the view immediately.I would want the view to update , like it would with 'refetchEvents'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was getting the results as an array with ajax, when the refetchResources was called the array was updated but not rendered in the Calendar.

In the fullcalendar.io docs it says

> If the resources option was specified as an function, it will be recalled. If the resources option was specified as a JSON feed it will be requested again.

So all I did was to get the results from a function inside the fullcalendar options as you write in the question with some updates

```
 resources: function(callback){
              if(t.someParam)  {
                 rooms=[{id: 1, title: 'It is TRUE!'},{id: 2, title: 'Resource 2'}]
              }
              else{
                rooms=[{id: 3, title: 'It is False!'},{id: 4, title: 'Resource 4'}]
                  }
                  callback(rooms);
                }
```

Then added a custom button wich changes the value of t.someParam and calls the refetch

```
 customButtons: {
    addRemoveResource: {
         text: 'refetchResources',
         click: function() {
         t.someParam=!t.someParam;
         $calendar.fullCalendar('refetchResources');
        }
  }
```

Try this  http://jsbin.com/gaviwuwave/edit?html,js,output

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14529645)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I updated the answer with more info on the solution.